# Generate new byte[] from existing byte[]

Tags: java, arrays

I would like to generate a "new" byte array from an existing one, without having to actually allocate from the heap.  In other words, the "new" byte array should share the same underlying data as the existing one.  The catch is that I would like the new byte array to have a different length.

```
byte[] buffer = { 0x01, 0x02, 0x04, 0x08, 0x10 };
byte[] shared = slice(buffer, 1, 3);
/* shared should be { 0x02, 0x04, 0x08 } and have length of 3 */
```

I'm doing this because I have a byte array from which I need to extract a packet, then pass that packet into a single-parameter method which only takes a `byte[]`.  I want to avoid making a copy of the data contained in the packet.  For my purposes, it can be assumed that the contents of `buffer` will not change within the scope of `shared`.

Is this possible?  It seems like a common thing one would want to do when working with buffers.  Thanks in advance,

Comment: I think you can do this with ArrayList...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it is not possible in Java to have different `byte[]` that (partly) share the same memory.

Instead of using `byte[]`, you could use [`java.nio.ByteBuffer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html) which does allow you to slice a buffer in the way you want to.

```
ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(new byte[]{ 0x01, 0x02, 0x04, 0x08, 0x10 });

buffer.position(1);
buffer.limit(4);

ByteBuffer shared = buffer.slice();
```

Note that the `ByteBuffer` returned by `buffer.slice()` refers to the same underlying byte array as the original buffer.

Comment: At least SOMEone mentions `ByteBuffer` (which is intended for exactly this case, and has a built-in `slice` method). It's a pity that `Buffer`s are otherwise rather inflexible (all the concrete classes should have been interfaces!).

Comment: Thanks.  I had already tried this, hoping that `ByteBuffer.wrap(buffer, 1, 3).slice().array()` would work.  But as you say, it sadly will just return the original buffer.

Comment: @pathfinderelite Yes, Java really does not have different arrays that share the same memory. So you can't have this by trying to use a trick! `ByteBuffer.array` returns the whole underlying array. The way to do this is to let your methods work with `ByteBuffer` instead of `byte[]`.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortuantely, it is impossible for two separate arrays to occupy the same memory space but be of different lengths. They would have to be two variables pointing to the same object in memory.

Can you not just pass the byte array to the method? From how I interpreted your question, this is what you are trying to achieve.

```
byte[] array = packet.bytes;
byte[] slicedArray = slice(array, 1, 3);
method(slicedArray);
```

Comment: No, `buffer` contains excess bytes that should not be a part of the byte array passed into the method.

Comment: @pathfinderelite Forgot to edit the passed variable name when editing my post.

Comment: `slice()` is the imaginary method I would like to exist :)

Answer (score -1):

You can try this:

```
byte[] buffer = { 0x01, 0x02, 0x04, 0x08, 0x10 };
byte[] shared = Arrays.copyOfRange(buffer, 1, 4);
/* shared should be { 0x02, 0x04, 0x08 } and have length of 3 */
```

Comment: That makes a copy of part of the original array, which is exactly what pathfinderelite is trying to avoid.